# Change cell value after data entered

Tags: excel

I know I can change the color of a cell based on value entered using conditional formatting, but is it possible to change the value entered?

E.g. letter "T" is entered into a cell, when that cell loses focus I want the "T" to change to a "1", a "G" to a "2", a "D" to change to a "3" etc etc

This applies to all cells within a row and various columns. Is this possible?

I tried with adding a formula on a cell but it told me it was circular reference which I get.

Quite new to Excel.

Comment: Could you please include the formula that you tried in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with the VBA Worksheet SelectionChange event:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static PrevRange As Range
    If Not PrevRange Is Nothing Then
        If Not PrevRange.HasFormula Then
            If OldRange.Value = "T" Then
                OldRange.Value = "1"
            Else If OldRange.Value = "G" Then
                OldRange.Value = "2"
            Else If OldRange.Value = "D" Then
                OldRange.Value = "3"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Set PrevRange = Target.Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a lookup table (where the resulting values would not be entered in the same cell, but perhaps immediately adjacent, by formula).

However if prepared to enter `=T` rather than just `T` you could apply what would be almost a modified version of a lookup with Defined Names. I would not recommend this approach however for single character names.